# Separate spring authenticator server from resource

Tags: spring, api, rest, security, jwt

i m new with spring security.
I want to know if it's possible to have jwt authentication server separate from resource server,
If possible i need a working example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could find an example with Oauth2 and Spring Boot 2.1.9.RELEASE here:
https://github.com/buddhiprab/springboot-oauth2-separating-authorization_server-and-resource_server

All the explanation of this example is here: https://medium.com/@buddhiprabhath/spring-boot-oauth-2-0-separating-authorization-service-and-resource-service-1641ebced1f0
This is doing with the client-credentials flow from OAuth2.

Here is another example using password flow:
https://www.javainuse.com/spring/springboot-oauth2-password-grant

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that shows a separate auth and resource server.  This is from Joe Grandja, who is one of the primary authors of Spring Security:

- Old way; Spring Security version 5.1 or earlier with separate `spring-security-oauth` library: https://github.com/jgrandja/spring-security-oauth-2-4-migrate
- New way; Spring Security 5.2+: https://github.com/jgrandja/spring-security-oauth-5-2-migrate

Answer (score 0):

Thank`s everyone! i start to understand how it works! i want to integrate jwt now!